# Convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{x_n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2$ are convergent ($x_n \neq -1$).

What can be said about the convergence of series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{x_n+1}\ \text{?}$$

Comment: It is convergent.

Comment: why??? It seems that it is conditionally convergent.

Comment: What can **you** say about it?

Answer (score 7):

Hint: note that as $x_n\to 0$ (as $\sum x_n$ is convergent) and $x_n\not =-1$ for all $n$, there exist $c>0$ such that $|1+x_n|\geq c$ for all $n$. Now write $\frac{x_n}{1+x_n}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2}{1+x_n}$.

Comment: Very nice solution! :) +1